# kafka @Listener exception handling - unable to configure batch Retry

Tags: java, error-handling, listener, spring-kafka

I am very new to `Kafka`. I am trying to figure out and understand how the error scenarios will work for `@Listener batch consumer factory`.

#### What I am doing ...

I am consuming records from a `topic` in `batch` process and inserting them into `DB` like below ...

```
@KafkaListener( topics = "KAFKA.TEST")
public Boolean listen(List<ConsumerRecord<String, User>> list)  throws Exception {
    Boolean result = null;
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, User> record : list) {
        User user = record.value();
        userList.add(user);
    }
    if(userList.size()>0) {
        result = dbService.insertBatchUser(userList);
        LOGGER.info(" users inserted " + userList.size());
    }
    else
        LOGGER.info(" No users found in the topic ");

    countDownLatch.countDown();
    return result;
}
```

#### My Question

1. How to retry if any batch processing failed to insert into DB due to DB unavailability
2. How to test if Kafka server is running and able to connect to the specific topic - why I am asking this question is I tried `Kafka Listener` after stopping `zookeeper` and `Kafka` server locally but NO error or exceptions got. `Kafka Producer` I mean the `Template` to send message threw error after stopping the `Kafka Server` but no ERRORs found at `Listener`

#### ADDED

#### My Configuration

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory consumerFactory(){
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(consumerConfigs(),stringKeyDeserializer(),jsonValueDeserializer());
}
@Bean
public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy(){
    SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(getMaxRetryAttempts());
    return simpleRetryPolicy;
}

@Bean
public FixedBackOffPolicy getBackOffPolicy() {
    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(getRetryInterval());
    return backOffPolicy;
}

@Bean
public RetryTemplate getRetryTemplate(){
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(getRetryPolicy());
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(getBackOffPolicy());
    return retryTemplate;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConcurrency(getConcurrency());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(getPollTimeout());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(getRetryTemplate());
    return factory;
}
```

Here I am using `org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate`

#### Exception I got

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter cannot be cast to org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupMessageListener(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:306) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:282) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Retrying Deliveries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_retrying_deliveries).

> When using @KafkaListener, set the RetryTemplate (and optionally recoveryCallback) on the container factory and the listener will be wrapped in the appropriate retrying adapter.

The new Kafka client (0.9.x.x or 0.10.x.x) doesn't talk to zookeeper directly just the kafka server itself.

The client internally keeps trying to reconnect; turn on debug logging to see the activity.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried adding `RetryTemplate` to my `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` but getting exception `java.lang.ClassCastException:org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter cannot be cast to org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener` ... I have added my configuration here

Comment: Edit your question to add the configuration.

Comment: sorry, I added the details, please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh - we don't currently provide a retry adapter for batch listeners - the problem is we don't know where in the batch to retry from. You might have processed some of the records successfully. You would need to use the retrytemplate within your listener directly. See [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_retrying_deliveries) `A retry adapter is not provided for any of the batch message listeners.`

Comment: Thanks. I need to go through the document  once again to understand it more and come up with right solution for my error scenario case. Thanks a loot for your time

Comment: @GaryRussell why don't you retry from the beginning? kafka promises for at least once anyways. it is better than not having an option for it. :(

Comment: Yes, we could do that (in fact the `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` does exactly that, but there is no back-off between deliveries). However, in general, it would be better to use a `RetryTemplate` within the batch listener itself since it knows which record in the list is failing.

Comment: @GaryRussell  -  Does it mean, we can't have retryTemplate without errorHandler ?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers; in any case, it's not clear what you mean. Ask a new question with much more detail. This is an old answer; the error handlers have evolved greatly since then; a `RetryTemplate` is generally no longer needed.